# Codeigniter multiple upload with different area name and rename the file before uploaded

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I have a problem with multiple files upload with different area name and want to change for every area filename before it's upload.

This is HTML form.

```
<input type="file" placeholder="" name="profilPic"/>
<input type="file" placeholder="" name="topPic"/>
```

This is controller

```
    $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']             = 100;
    $config['max_width']            = 1024;
    $config['max_height']           = 768;
    //$config['file_name']          = $this->session->sersession["id"];
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $profilPic = $this->upload->do_upload('profilPic');
    if (!$profilPic){
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->session->set_flashdata("error", "profil pic was not uploaded= ");
    }else{
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $this->session->set_flashdata("success", "profil picture was uploaded.");
    }
    $topPic = $this->upload->do_upload('topPic');
    if (!$topPic){
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->session->set_flashdata("error", "top pic was not uploaded" );

    }else{
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $this->session->set_flashdata("success", "this picture was uploaded.");
    }
```

Note: The pictures are upload to directory. But i want to rename every file file name before uploaded like "userID_profil.jpg" and "userID_top.jpg"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it.

```
    $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']             = 100;
    $config['max_width']            = 1024;
    $config['max_height']           = 768;
    if($_FILES["profilPic"]["name"]){
        $config["file_name"] = $this->session->usersession["id"]."_profil.jpg";
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $profilPic = $this->upload->do_upload('profilPic');
        if (!$profilPic){
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->session->set_flashdata("error", ".");
        }else{
            $profilPic = $this->upload->data("file_name");
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            $this->session->set_flashdata("success", ".");
        }
    }

    if($_FILES["topPic"]["name"]){
        $config["file_name"] = $this->session->usersession["id"]."_top.jpg";
        if($_FILES["profilPic"]["name"]){
            $this->upload->initialize($config);
        }else{
            $this->loadl->library('upload', $config);
        }
        $topPic = $this->upload->do_upload('topPic');
        if (!$topPic){
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->session->set_flashdata("error", "" );
        }else{
            $topPic = $this->upload->data("file_name");
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            $this->session->set_flashdata("success", ".");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set the `$config['file_name']` before the second file upload using

```
$this->upload->initialize($config);
```

Of course, you also need to set it for the first file either with `$this->load->library('upload', $config)` or `$this->upload->initialize($config)`.

Docs: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html#setting-preferences